# Validation of prefilled contact form fields in Magento fails

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My Magento contact form has the field names prefilled, not labelled.

```
<input name="name" id="name" value="Name" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
```

Since the field is prefilled, the validation "required-entry" fails.
Is there a not-so-dirty way to get the validation working with prefilled values?

Comment: why u want prefilled ? is it for like label for text box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try to use.  [Placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder) to make prefilled text

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

that would sure help you.

Comment: @cari,glad to help you,

Comment: sry, i cant accept this as an answer, since it doesnt work in ie9:-/

Comment: ok, i will accept this now and try to workaround the ie9 problem with jquery placeholder plugin @ https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: ok but rather than to load exra lib to page if ie9 is not concern then we should have to use default html5 tags

Comment: well, ie9 is still a concern for every serious website.. :-(